# Flex Viewstack dyanmic next and back buttons

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I'm trying to create a wizard that will guide a user through a lot of individual containers I have built.  I have a main page that has many checkboxes for the user, each checkbox ties to a container.  What I would like to have happen is once a checkbox is clicked it makes that container visible, then the next and back buttons when clicked only go to the next visible container; thereby leaving off any containers from the wizard that were not checked on the main page.  Any ideas, I've looked in a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array. When the user selects a check box add the containers name to the array. Then make a function to navigate back/forward through the array and show/hide the containers they reference.

Another option you might try is when the check box is checked, add the container to the view stack dynamically. Or have a button to start the wizard that loops through the check boxes and removes the containers from the view stack that are not checked.

Many ways to do it.

Comment: Duh, I'll give you the win since you made me pull my head out.  I wound up just writing a function and calling it for the box.

Comment: public function checkThis():void{
    if (one.selected)
     new.selectedChild=equip;
    else if new.selectedChild=directions;